# I need to print signal strength from the app using Appium and python (pytest)

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, appium-android

I am testing a mobile app that analyses the WiFi signal strength from a list (by selecting any from the list) measured in dBm. Using Appium and pytest I need to automate getting to one of the Wifi SSID and based on the data that is coming from the app to print the information (per second).

I am new with this and I know how to find elements/click/type but for a reason I cannot figure it out how to get the generated data from the device and put it in my code.

Tried to print the logcat but is not enough (I need to print every second the information for 60 seconds)

The only code I have is how to reach that section, but not to get what I need